# How can I store POST data with @angular/pwa in angular 8 when Offline, and update it to the server When Online?

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I've been trying to make my Angular application work completely offline.
Meaning I want all of my requests to be cached including the **POST** requests on IndexedDB through a Service worker.

I have installed @angular/pwa package to implement offline functionality. So far the App is able to load when I'm offline and it's also caching all the **GET** requests from the application. But It's not  caching the **POST** requests (which is expected).

So I tried implementing a custom Service worker to do my job.

I created 2 new files

1. `sw-master.js`
2. `sw-sync.js`

Inside sw-master.js

```
importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js');
importScripts('./sw-sync.js');
```

Inside sw-sync.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
        console.log(event.request);
    });
});
```

Inside app.module.ts, instead of this

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
```

I Put

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('sw-master.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
```

But the `console.log` inside the `sw-sync.js` -> `fetch` event is not working. I assume it's because there is a `fetch` event in `ngsw-worker.js` which has been generated by angular when compiled.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.